# UIButton placed on top of tableviewcell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have UIButton which is placed on top of each UITableviewCell . It is custom tableview . When i click on tableviewcell it goes into another tableview where (Tableview) contains the data in each cell .

This is the way i get the details of the 2nd tableview ....***customCellData*** is the db query method which gives out the cell number ..(Ex if i click 2nd cell of first tableview customcell returns the value ) 
(***bookArray*** - contains the list of items present in 2nd cell of first tableviewcell)

The following code is **didSelectForRowAtIndexPath**

```
 NSDictionary *selectedAuthor = nil;

     NSArray *sectionArray=[mainIndexDictionary objectForKey:[allKeysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
        selectedAuthor = [sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        iPath=[[selectedAuthor objectForKey:@"SymptIndexID"] intValue];
        NSLog(@"iPath - %d",iPath);

        authortitleString=[[selectedAuthor objectForKey:@"authorIndexName"]stringByAppendingString:@" cure!"];
    }


    bookArray=[objDB customCellData:(NSInteger)iPath];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:authorView];
    [bookTableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0,10.0) animated:NO];

    [bookTableView reloadData]
```

Now i want to program in such a way where .when i click on the UIButton which is there in 1st tableview it should contain the data of the 2nd tableview . I cant access indexPath since i will be doing this in seperate method ***( In didselectrowatindexpath if i give indexpath for that particular cell the indexpath is found )***

Will anyone please help me .

***Updated Code***

```
in cellForRowAtIndexPath 
  cell.shareFacebookButton.tag = indexPath.row;
            [cell.shareFacebookButton addTarget:self action:@selector(facebookShare:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            return cell;


    -(IBAction)facebookShare:(id)sender
    {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)button.superview.superview;
        UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)cell.superview;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

        NSInteger indexPathNumber = indexPath.row;

        NSLog(@"IndexPath is -- > %d" , indexPathNumber);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer Updated**

Ok, Below is the function you need to use for custom cell buttons

"cellForRowAtIndexPath" or use any other given appropriate function.

And to identify which button was clicked, do as below

```
<buttonid>.tag = <indexPath>.row;
```

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: Ravi .. in this method .how to find out which button is pressed. how can i access cell.shareButton (button on top of tableviewcell)..since b utton is created in custom cell . in customcell.m file i have added button on top of tableviewcell. I am new to this .can u help me out .. Thanks

Comment: i tried to implement ur way . When i do that iPath returns the indexPath number . when i run the project and if i click say 3rd IndexPath ipath = 3 .. when i click the button on same indexPath (indexPathNumber = 2) ..check my updated code

Comment: Dude, indexPath starts with 0 not 1. You just need to do +1 in your code. This has resolved your main issue so please accept the answer. Regards,